# What is the best GC and memory configuration for a real-time system that wants to minimize GC latency on a regular Sun/Oracle Hotspot JVM?

Tags: java, optimization, memory, garbage-collection

The question pretty much says it all. What supported JVM GC should we use and with what configuration to minimize GC impact in the application?

**EDIT:** Linux Ubuntu 64-bit:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Interesting article [here](http://worldmodscode.wordpress.com/2011/12/26/practical-garbage-collection-part-1-introduction/).

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: The Sun Hotspot VM isn't a real-time JVM, so you cannot possibly get 'real-time' performance out of it. So you are barking up the wrong tree. Or maybe you don't really mean 'real-time', you just mean something like 'real-world'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting in J2SE 5.0, the ***parallel collector*** is selected by default on server-class machines as detailed in the document Garbage Collector Ergonomics. In addition, the ***parallel collector uses a method of automatic tuning*** that allows desired behaviors to be specified instead of generation sizes and other low-level tuning details. The behaviors that can be specified are:

***Maximum garbage collection pause time***
Throughput
Footprint (i.e., heap size)
The maximum pause time goal is specified with the command line option -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=. This is interpreted as a hint that pause times of  milliseconds or less are desired; by default there is no maximum pause time goal. If a pause time goal is specified, the heap size and other garbage collection related ***parameters are adjusted in an attempt to keep garbage collection pauses shorter than the specified value***. Note that these adjustments may cause the garbage collector to reduce the overall throughput of the application and in some cases the desired pause time goal cannot be met.

Excerpted from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.ergonomics

Comment: Try something akin to the following options for VM options:

`-server
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=5
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+UseCompressedStrings
-XX:+UseBiasedLocking
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g`

Comment: Hey Chuck and Chris. Thanks for your help. I am already minimizing garbage creation. I guess the ideal situation is when GC is triggered the least possible times. Also, my application will hold many objects in memory (referenced objects), so this cannot be a burden for the GC. I heard that mark-and-sweep will not like that amount of memory.

Comment: @JohnPristine - Java GC's haven't used mark-sweep technology since the really early versions.  There is a lot of misinformed / out-of-date rubbish on the internet about Java GC.  You should pay closest attention to what Sun / Oracle's docs say.

Answer (score 8):

You've been asking questions about this problem for a number of days.  I think the root of your problems is that you are trying to get realtime performance out of Java platforms that are simply not designed to provide it.

If you want real-time performance (in the true sense of the word), you need a Java VM that implement the RTSJ realtime extensions.  [This page](http://rtjava.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/real-time-java-vms.html) that lists some implementations.  Note that to get realtime performance at the Java application level, you also need to be running on a real-time capable OS platform.

---

On the other hand, if you just want low-pause garbage collection without any strong realtime performance guarantees, then Oracle's GC tuning documents explain how to do this.  See Chuck Fricano's answer.

But beware that there limits to what can be achieved this way.  In particular, if your application stresses the GC too much, it won't be able to meet your goals for pause times.  And the optimal settings for the tuning parameters are likely to be platform / hardware specific, as well as application dependent.

There are no easy answers.

And there is certainly no one-size-fits-all configuration to minimize latency.  Not even for a specific JVM version, operating system and hardware platform.

Comment: Please note that the question title was changed after I wrote this answer. Even so, it is still a valid answer to say that that you can't get guaranteed real-time performance from a regular HotSpot JVM. You may not like this fact, but that doesn't make it false.

Answer (score 2):

In order to properly configure the GC you need to understand the object life cycle in your application.  As mentioned, there are no easy answers.  What has worked for me is sizing the young generation so most objects die there and using the CMS and setting an initiating fraction so it wont run constantly.  Here are my parameters:

`-server -Xms4000M -Xmx4000M -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=4 -XX:MaxNewSize=384m -XX:NewSize=384m -XX:SurvivorRatio=12 -Xloggc:/opt/logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`

You can also use third party utilities to parse the GC log files in order to see statistics on the collector.